# Arduino Sends Old Data Through Serial

Tags: arduino

I think my problem would best be explained with an example. Here is some Arduino Code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(millis());
  delay(1);
}
```

...and here is the output:

[image: Arduino Output]

Now, those numbers at the beginning aren't just your regular old first-bytes-of-serial-data-are-always-messed-up numbers. Those numbers are left over from the last time I opened the serial monitor. How do I know this? Because I counted how many seconds had gone by since I last opened the serial monitor, and it all matched up.

So here's the big questioroonie,

How do I make this stop? It's breaking my java program that's supposed to read data from the Arduino's current "run instance"(I don't know the correct term), and not the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your Arduino.  Remember, the USB connection is not a real RS-232 serial interface, it's simulated through USB.  And that USB connection is controlled by a chip with its own buffer.

Bad news is, nothing you can do if you're using the USB cable to carry your RS-232 signals, other than to send some "filler characters" to purge the buffer.  Too many buffers everywhere :)  Send some terminal emulation commands like "clear the screen" and "form feed" etc. to empty the pipeline of stuff in the buffer.

Which reminds me --  we should all quit using the crummy Arduino serial monitor and be vocal about it.  Instead, use TeraTerm or Putty or any other good-quality terminal emulator of your choice.

Or connect with real RS232 and an adapter and cable.  My development machine has three serial ports, but that's what I do.  Often computers today don't even have one handy.