# Getting old and new data in an array on serialport - Arduino uno, nodejs, socket.io and sensor

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, sockets, arduino-uno

I have attached a sensor to arduino and I am trying to pull those data using a serial port into Nodejs. Which I will be using it to make a graph.

Data pushed from serial port, when printed on a terminal looks like this:

```
1,2

1,2
1,3

1,2
1,3
1,4

1,2
1,3
1,4
1,5
```

As you can see all the previous data is pushed again :/ I dont want that

Expected output

```
1,2
1,3
1,4
1,5
1,6
```

format here : `<value 1> , <value 2>`

later I will be splitting these incoming data and push it as 2 different datasets, in-order to get a graph like this:

http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/multi-axis.html

## code - nodejs

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport");
var serialport = new SerialPort("COM4");

var received = "";
 serialport.on('open', function(){
    console.log('Serial Port Opend');

    serialport.on('data', function(data){
      received += data.toString();
      console.log("incoming data: " + received);
    nsp.emit('live-data', received);
  });
});
```

## Serial output code from arduino

```
void serialOutput(){   // Decide How To Output Serial.
  switch(outputType){
    case PROCESSING_VISUALIZER:
      sendDataToSerial('S', Signal);     // goes to sendDataToSerial function
      break;
    case SERIAL_PLOTTER:  // open the Arduino Serial Plotter to visualize these data
      Serial.print(BPM);
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.println(Signal);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

}
```

Comment: Please see my [previous answer on this leftover old data behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261608/arduino-sends-old-data-through-serial/45264333#45264333).

Comment: @JLH I see, you are saying that's how arduino would behave and you are suggesting to use putty or TeraTerm or use RS232 itself. this was my first project ever with hardware and with arduino so I am not sure what is RS232 or how to use that. Can you show how to use putty to avoid those duplicates? or could you share a link that could guide me achieve tht? it would be great help and I can accept your answer too.

Comment: As I said in that answer, "Bad news is, nothing you can do if you're using the USB cable to carry your RS-232 signals, other than to send some "filler characters" to purge the buffer."  Or connect with real RS232.